# Extracting data with Twitter Api

Tags: twitter, extract, twitter4j

I am writing a small program that polling tweets from twitter with twitter4j search API,but it seems that this API only returns tweets that were posted within last week,is there any way to get all the tweets under specific keywords from twitter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get tweets from only past 7 days using Twitter search in REST API.

If your application needs more than this, start using Streaming API. You can start saving the tweets you get in a database for later access.

Example: http://davidcrowley.me/?p=435

Comment: Hi Ramannan thanks for answering my question,but the problem is with streaming API you can only get tweets that after you start your program right?is there any way to get all the earlier tweets ?

Comment: Yes, in Streaming API you can get tweets from the moment you start. You may search for tweets analyzer websites. But they may cost you to use. http://www.pamorama.net/2010/04/26/20-top-twitter-monitoring-and-analytics-tools/